# How to insert multiple lines with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to add this

```
#this 
##is my 
text
```

before the line

```
the specific line
```

I tried this

```
sed -i '/the specific line/i \
#this 
##is my 
text
' text.txt
```

but it only adds in 'text'.

I also tried various combinations with `\` and `" "` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With newlines:

```
% sed -i '/the specific line/i #this\n##is my\ntext' foo

% cat foo
#this
##is my
text
the specific line
```

Answer (score 19):

You're missing the trailing backslash at the end of some lines (and you have an eccessive newline at the end of the last line you want to insert):

```
sed -i '/the specific line/i \
#this\
##is my\
text' file
```

```
% cat file
foo
the specific line
bar

% sed -i '/the specific line/i \
#this\
##is my\
text' file

% cat file
foo
#this 
##is my 
text
the specific line
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

When the replacement string has newlines and spaces, you can use something else. We will try to insert the output of `ls -l` in the middle of some template file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next}
    /Insert index here/ {for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) { print a[i] }}
    {print}'
    <(ls -l) text.txt
```

When you want something inserted after a line, you can move the command  `{print}` or switch to :

```
sed '/Insert command output after this line/r'<(ls -l) text.txt
```

You can also use sed for inserting before a line with

```
sed 's/Insert command output after this line/ls -l; echo "&"/e' text.txt
```